# Write a script that add rows

Tags: sql-server

I am learning SQL on my own and have been trying to work on some exercises. I have tried answering these questions below but i just can't seem to get them right and i'm becoming frustrated (which i shouldn't). I have read the book and the examples but when I try, i get errors.

3. Write a script that adds rows to the Myth database. The database has three tables: Users,Downloads and Products.

a.  Add two rows to the Users and Products tables.

My answer:

```
INSERT into users values(‘user 1’,’user 2’);
INSERT into Products values(‘products 1’,‘products 2’)
```

b.  Add three rows to the Downloads table: one row for user 1 and product 2; one for user 2 and product 1; and one for user 2 and product 2. Use the GET DATE function to insert the current date and time into the Download Date column.

My answer:

```
INSERT INTO Downloads VALUES('user 1','Product 2',GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Downloads VALUES('user 2',' Product 1',GETDATE());
INSERT INTO Downloads VALUES('user 2',' Product 2',GETDATE());
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: So, what is the error you are getting?   Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. The table users has UserId, emailaddress, firstname, lastname. The product tables has ProductID and ProductName. I just created a database with these columns and I need to use that database to inster these rows.

Comment: What are the table definitions?

Comment: Something very similar here: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/1-write-script-adds-index-myguitarshop-database-zip-code-field-customers-table-2-write-scr-q5194896

Comment: none of the code below worked as it stated that identifier was set off

Answer (score 0):

The error means that either

1. You are inserting data into columns which do not exist
2. They aren't in the correct order.

Based on your comments, you have an error in the `User` table to start. Since you didn't state which rows were `NULL` or *nullable* or if the primaryKey was auto generated, you need to insert a value for each of the columns. By default, the columns will not be *nullable* meaning you **must** insert a value. You also didn't state what the data types were for the columns, so these are assumptions:

```
INSERT into users (UserId, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName)
values
(1,'me@domain.com','Joe','Dirt'),   --row 1
(2,'you@domain.com','Jane','Doe');  --row 2
```

The same goes for the `products` table

```
INSERT into Products (ProductId, ProductName)
values
(1,'products 1'),
(2,'products 2');
```

The issue could be the order of your insert. You'll notice i explicitly list the order of the insert above via `INSERT into SomeTable (col1, col2, ...)`. You can change the order here, as long as the insert order matches what you list. When you don't explicitly list it int eh `INSERT`, your inserted data must match the column definition. The order for `Downloads` is (DownloardId, UserId, DownloardDate, FileName, ProductID). So the insert, without explicitly listing it, would be like so:

```
Insert into Downloads  
values
(1,1,getdate(),'my file',1),
(2,1,getdate(),'my file2',2),
(3,2,getdate(),'my file3',1);
```

Note, you didn't list any foreign keys, but you'll want to research this. The `UserId, ProductID` in the `Downloads` table is almost certainly a foreign key that references the `Users` and `Products` tables.

Comment: I used the code you provided but still getting the same error:Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: you have to elaborate. You need to post what the table structure is for those tables as Tab Alleman stated in the comments. However, I'm confident the answer is correct since that's the common issue.

Comment: Users Table colums are :                                                                   
UserId(the is the primary key),                                                    
EmailAddress,                                                                                  
FirstName,                                                                                         
LastName

Product Table colums are:                                                            
ProductId(the is the primary key),                                                
ProductName

Comment: I created the database based on these table definitions. The database does not have any values in it The next question is then to add two rows to the users and products tables. I have used the codes provided prior to posting the question but was getting the same errors. Not sure what else I did wrong. I went through the book Murach's sql for developers, 2016, the chapter about inserting row. I followed it yet something is not working.

Comment: @Scismon, when i created the database, the productID and userID were entered as foreign keys in the Downloads table. Below is the script I wrote to create the database:       CREATE TABLE Downloads(
DownloadID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
UserID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID),
DownloadDate datetime NOT NULL,
FileName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
ProductID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products(ProductID)
);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure the solution out. On the first question, I didn't need to add the UserID because I defined its field as an integer primary key. As such, it will automatically add the next value.
With regards to the products one, I needed to set the identifier on and off. Once I did, it all work out.
Thank you for all your assistance.